# howto to setup a remote share in a standalone linux workstation with user/passwd

Tags: samba

I have a linux workstation in which I want to offer an access to a share folder using  a user login and password.
All files remotely created will belong to the local workstation user named operator

in my linux workstation, I created this special account  PenguinUser as user login for this share :

```
    sudo useradd --no-create-home PenguinUser
    sudo smbpasswd -a PenguinUser
```

I setted up the samba server as follow :

```
[global]
        workgroup = OUTOFWORLD
        server string = SHARED MACHINE
        security = user
        map to guest = Bad Password
        passdb backend = tdbsam
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        guest account = operator
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n .
        logging = syslog@0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        load printers = No
        show add printer wizard = No
        dns proxy = No
        ldap ssl = no
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        invalid users = root
        usershare allow guests = No

[files]
        comment = operator files
        path = /home/operator/files_folder
        valid users = operator,PenguinUser
        read list = operator
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        force user = operator
        force group = automat
        guest ok = No
        browseable = Yes
        writable = Yes
```

2 questions :
1/ why do we need to create a user account in the main company server ?? In this case, I would agree, if it is possible to manage the user / login password from this server and not the workstation ?

2/ Howto allow write accesses in the folders created in the remote directory ? This actual setup does not permit it.

Answer (score 0):

1/ why do we need to create a user account in the main company server ??

So that the Samba users can save files to the share

1A/ In this case, I would agree, if it is possible to manage the user / login password from this server and not the workstation ?

Big problem, you can add 'unix password sync = yes' to '[global]' and this will keep the Unix & Samba passwords in sync on the server, but there is nothing standard that will keep the client password in sync with the server, why do you think they came up with domains ? (note: that wasn't the only reason)

2/ Howto allow write accesses in the folders created in the remote directory ? This actual setup does not permit it.

recreate your smb.conf like this:

```
[global]
        workgroup = OUTOFWORLD
        server string = SHARED MACHINE
        security = user
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\sUNIX\spassword:* %n\n .
        unix password sync = yes
        logging = syslog@0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 50
        load printers = No
        show add printer wizard = No
        dns proxy = No
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d

[files]
        comment = operator files
        path = /home/files_folder
        valid users = PenguinUser
        create mask = 0700
        directory mask = 0700
        read only = no
```

This will allow only the user 'PenguinUser' to connect to the 'files' share.